# TDD in Sharepoint Mocking/Testing user privilages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, nunit

Is there any way to run sharepoint TDD nunint test and mocking user permissions eg: user is in some group or has some privilages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm...good question! SharePoint was not designed with testability in mind. In general, unit testing in SharePoint is not that cut and dried.

Check out [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-for-sharepoint-produc) product for unit testing SharePoint. The TypeMock Isolator allows you to fake calls to SharePoint so that you can run unit tests against the SharePoint object model without actually having SharePoint installed or going to a specific instance of SharePoint 2010.

As promising as the tool may sound, I really doubt if you can run unit tests on user privileges. After all you would want to check user privileges against a real SharePoint instance and not mock object right? I mean my point is that if you do not want to access SharePoint to check user privileges then you are not actually TDDing SharePoint.

If you still decide to go ahead with TDD in this case then all you need to do is create a mock object (use any mocking library) that returns a boolean. If all you are doing is checking that user has access or user belongs to a group, it is not that different than a simple stub that gives you a boolean.